# What's a sophisticated synonym for "cooking"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that essentially means "to cook" but sounds fancy and sophisticated. What synonyms are there?

**Edit:**

As for context, I'm thinking of a restaurant setting.

Comment: Tangent: The Online Etymology Dictionary has some interesting things to say about the word "cook". Turns out it's not quite as Germanic as I thought, but quite an old word nonetheless. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cook

Comment: Reading the title, the word *cuisine* immediately came to mind. But that's *cooking* as a noun, not as a verb.

Comment: @Rahul: yeah as well as `Haute cuisine` (French: literally "high cooking")

Comment: in a general setting, or when referring to a particular type of food being cooked?

Comment: "be slaving away over a hot stove" - not fancy but can get you brownie points from http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/american/Cook-food-or-be-cooked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a more general verb like:

- prepare
- craft
- create

And then sprinkle various more flowery adverbs, nouns and adjectives to make it sound more sophisticated. Try not to overdo it.

> At Restaurant X, your meal is skillfully prepared from locally-sourced, fresh, organic ingredients.

If you're writing about a specific dish, you may want to use a verb that specifies the method of cooking, like:

- grill
- sautée
- roast
- sear

etc.

> At Restaurant X, our aged prime rib is slow-roasted to perfection.

Comment: Sautée sounds like what I want.

Answer (score 5):

Just kidding: "Endow with a pleasant thermo-chemical alteration."

Nouns seems to be aplenty, but somehow not verbs. Perhaps you could concoct a verb out of the following nouns:

1. Gastronome
2. Epicure
3. Gourmet
4. Gourmand

Other leads might follow by chasing words strongly associated with:

1. Fix
2. Prepare
3. Fabricate
4. Conjure
5. Decoct
   ...

Perhaps, if you could provide more context to your question, someone might be able to offer a more precise and useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Engaging in the Culinary Arts.

Comment: I'm looking for a word.

Answer (score 3):

**Concoct** (verb)

[Definition from Encarta:](http://encarta.msn.com/encnet/features/dictionary/DictionaryResults.aspx?refid=1861599361)

> 1. mix ingredients to make something new: to create something by mixing or
>      combining various ingredients in a new
>      way, especially in cooking

---

Examples:

- [And leisurely concoct their grassy meal. ...](http://books.google.com/books?id=wv3qmv0-iqQC&pg=PA1269&dq=concoct+meal&hl=en&ei=b60dTbuZCseIhQf5zJi3Dg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBg)
- [Masakazu Nonomura will concoct a progressive series of plates representing the history of Japan.](http://books.google.com/books?id=BF4EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA58&dq=concoct+meal&hl=en&ei=b60dTbuZCseIhQf5zJi3Dg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCQ)
- [You can concoct a fairly decent meal.](http://books.google.com/books?id=rKphXb6FiAcC&pg=PA93&dq=concoct+meal&hl=en&ei=-q4dTbSvMJSxhQfSvti3Dg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCIQ6AEwADgK)
- [Or let master bartenders concoct a refreshing ice cream or fruit juice drink.](http://books.google.com/books?id=Th8DAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA115&dq=concoct+meal&hl=en&ei=h64dTYD2MsawhQeYxrW3Dg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCcQ6AEwATgK)

Comment: but concoct often has negative connotations, and certainly does not sound "sophisticated"....

Comment: you think *concoct*, you think *magic potion* - at least for me

Comment: @JoseK -- I'd say that about _conjure_; shout-out to fellow mages out there.

Answer (score 0):

*Baking* and *boiling* are both decent synonyms.

(Depending on the context, of course.)